# Is there any way I can rewrite my methods better?

Tags: java, methods

I'm not entirely sure if there is an easier answer to this question and I'm thinking to hard about it or what, but I'm currently programming a rectangular block program to practice Java. It's structured to have 4 methods: `getInput`, `volBlock`, `saBlock`, and `display`, and I want to use only local variables for these methods. Is there a way that I can utilize getInput to accept and return a single double from the user and if so, how can I use that input in my other methods?

I constructed this code, which uses local variables in getInput() and then passes those values to other methods, but I couldn't figure out a display method so I hard coded it into the calculation methods themselves.

Here is that code:

```java
import java.util.*;
public class Block {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = "Y";
        while (choice.equals("Y")){
            getInput();
            System.out.println("Would you like to do another calculation?(Y/N): ");
            choice = in.next().toUpperCase();
        }
        System.out.println("Program now ending...");
    }

    public static void getInput() {
        double l, w, h;
        Scanner fin = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the length, width, and height in that order: ");
        l = fin.nextDouble();
        w = fin.nextDouble();
        h = fin.nextDouble();

        volBlock(l, w, h);
        surfaceAreaBlock(l,w,h);
    }

    public static void volBlock(double length, double width, double height) {
        double volume;

        volume = length * width * height;

        System.out.println("The volume is: " + volume);
    }

    public static void surfaceAreaBlock (double l, double w, double h) {
        double surfaceArea;

        surfaceArea = 2 * (l*h+l*w+h*w);

        System.out.println("The surface area is: " + surfaceArea);
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if this question is kind of scrambled, I am having a hard time figuring all of this out. I'm quite new to Java.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I think that you're missing the point of OOP. It would be more appropriate if you created a Block class that holds three doubles and implements `volume` and `surfaceArea` methods that return doubles, and your main should simply perform the input loop, construct a new Block, then call the appropriate methods to find the volume and surface area.

Answer (score 1):

If you're practicing java, you should probably familiarize yourself more with *object oriented programming* before you go any further, because your code leads me to believe that you're more used to procedural languages (e.g. C, C++, etc). Java doesn't rely on having several static helper methods in its main; the preferred approach is to construct a few classes that perform these calculations for you, and you use the results created by these functions for your basic input/output, which is normally what main is used for.

I implemented a block class to demonstrate what I mean:

```java
public class Block {
    private double length;
    private double width;
    private double height;

    public Block(double l, double w, double h) {
        length = l;
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }

    public double getVolume() {
        return length * width * height;
    }

    public double getSurfaceArea() {
        return 2 * length * (height + width) + height * width;
    }

    /* This is the "display" method that you want */
    public String toString() {
        return "The volume is: " + getVolume() + "\n"
               "The surface area is: " + getSurfaceArea();
    }
}
```

using the `Block` class, your main becomes much more simple:

```java
public static void main() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    char choice = 'y';

    do {
        System.out.print("Please enter the dimensions of the block: ");
        double length = in.nextDouble();
        double width  = in.nextDouble();
        double height = in.nextDouble();
        Block block = new Block(length, width, height);

        System.out.println(block);
        System.out.print("continue (y/n)? ");
        choice = in.nextLine.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
    } while (choice == 'y');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you return the values from your getInput(), volBlock() and surfaceAreaBlock() methods you might be able to structure the rest as you want to.

For instance surfaceAreaBlock becomes:

```
public static double surfaceAreaBlock (double l, double w, double h){
    double surfaceArea;

    surfaceArea = 2 * (l*h+l*w+h*w);

    return surfaceArea;
}
```

and then when you call surfaceAreaBlock you can do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...

    double surfaceArea = surfaceAreaBlock();

    // Do something with the surface area in this method
    ...
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to display the result of surfaceAreaBlock, how would I go about doing that in a separate method?

Comment: Making a new method and passing the surfaceArea in as a parameter is a good start. I'm sure you can figure the rest out.